# arc URL for images in local storage

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using [arc](https://github.com/stavro/arc) and [arc_ecto](https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto) to upload avatars for a `user` model. During development I'd like to use the local storage. The upload works but I don't know how to actually display the image.

I can display the file name but don't get the URL for the local storage to use it in an `<img>` tag. Do I have to use a different directory in the config or a different way to access it in the view?

**web/templates/user/show.html.eex**

```html
<h2>Show user</h2>

[...]

<%= MyApp.Avatar.url({@user.avatar, @user}, :original) %>
```

**web/uploaders/avatar.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Avatar do
  use Arc.Definition
  use Arc.Ecto.Definition

  @versions [:original, :thumb]

  def transform(:thumb, _) do
    {:convert, "-strip -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100"}
  end

  def __storage, do: Arc.Storage.Local

  def filename(version,  {file, scope}), do: "#{version}-#{file.file_name}"

  # Override the storage directory:
  def storage_dir(version, {file, scope}) do
    "web/static/assets/images/avatars/#{scope.id}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static assets like pictures are live under `priv/static/`. I am using special helper function for `arc` uploads in my apps.
Here is the code:

```
# helper
defmodule MyApp.AssetHelper do
  def upload_path(path) do
    case is_binary(path) do
      true ->
        path
        |> String.replace("priv/static/", "/")
      _ ->
        nil
    end
  end
end

# web/web.ex
  def view do
    quote do
      ....
      import MyApp.AssetHelper, only: [upload_path: 1]
      ....
      import MyApp.Router.Helpers
      import MyApp.ErrorHelpers
      import MyApp.Gettext
    end
  end

# view
defmodule MyApp.AvatarView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  def avatar_path(avatar) do
    MyApp.Avatar.url({avatar.image, avatar}, :thumb)
    |> upload_path
  end
end
```

Then you could use it in templates as ordinary view funcs